# What are the built-in routing algorithms of NS2?

Tags: networking, simulation, ns2

I'm doing a few small simulations in NS2 as part of an assignment. I chose the simulator myself, the only real requirement was to compare two routing algorithms.

So i've followed the tutorial provided by Marc Greis [here](http://www.isi.edu/nsnam/ns/tutorial/index.html)

Because of that i have used `$ns rtproto DV` to set the routing algorithm to 'dynamic routing'.

What are the other algorithms? Is there a default if I do not use the command above? Is there somewhere I can go to read about how they work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few algorithms implemented in ns2: DSR, DSDV, AODV, TORA.